# Criteria query no order using Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm trying to get a list of entities with their collection order by datetime, but I don't get it. This is my query:

```
trades = session.createCriteria(Trade.class)
    .createAlias("operations", "operations", CriteriaSpecification.INNER_JOIN)
    .add(Restrictions.between("operations.datetime", start, end))
    .addOrder(Order.asc("operations.datetime"))
    .setResultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY)
    .list();
```

According to hibernate these are the queries:

```
select 
    this_.MUREX_ID as MUREX1_0_1_, 
    this_.PORTFOLIO as PORTFOLIO0_1_, 
    this_.TYPE as TYPE0_1_, 
    operations1_.ID as ID1_0_, 
    operations1_.COMENT as COMENT1_0_, 
    operations1_.DATETIME as DATETIME1_0_, 
    operations1_.GBO_ID as GBO4_1_0_, 
    operations1_.OPERATION as OPERATION1_0_, 
    operations1_.OPERATION_ID as OPERATION6_1_0_, 
    operations1_.OPICS_ID as OPICS7_1_0_, 
    operations1_.STATUS_GBO as STATUS8_1_0_, 
    operations1_.STATUS_MUREX as STATUS9_1_0_, 
    operations1_.MUREX_ID as MUREX10_1_0_ 
from 
    PGT_NY.T_PGT_NY_BLOTTER_TRADES_S this_, 
    PGT_NY.T_PGT_NY_BLOTTER_OPERATIONS_S operations1_ 
where 
    this_.MUREX_ID=operations1_.MUREX_ID and 
    operations1_.DATETIME between ? and ? 
order by operations1_.DATETIME asc
```

And:

```
select 
    operations0_.MUREX_ID as MUREX10_1_, 
    operations0_.ID as ID1_, 
    operations0_.ID as ID1_0_, 
    operations0_.COMENT as COMENT1_0_, 
    operations0_.DATETIME as DATETIME1_0_, 
    operations0_.GBO_ID as GBO4_1_0_, 
    operations0_.OPERATION as OPERATION1_0_, 
    operations0_.OPERATION_ID as OPERATION6_1_0_, 
    operations0_.OPICS_ID as OPICS7_1_0_, 
    operations0_.STATUS_GBO as STATUS8_1_0_, 
    operations0_.STATUS_MUREX as STATUS9_1_0_, 
    operations0_.MUREX_ID as MUREX10_1_0_ 
from 
    PGT_NY.T_PGT_NY_BLOTTER_OPERATIONS_S operations0_ 
where 
    operations0_.MUREX_ID in (
        select 
            this_.MUREX_ID 
        from 
            PGT_NY.T_PGT_NY_BLOTTER_TRADES_S this_,
            PGT_NY.T_PGT_NY_BLOTTER_OPERATIONS_S operations1_ 
        where 
            this_.MUREX_ID=operations1_.MUREX_ID and 
            operations1_.DATETIME between ? and ? 
    )
```

Any help would be really useful.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks good to me. you should get a list of Trade's back which are sorted by datetime of their operations meaning the trade which has the operation with the smalles datetime comes first then the one with the operation with second smallest.

the collections on the trade objects are sorted as stated in the mappings. you have to sort them individually. Hibernate won't do it on loading because it would break change tracking of lists, indexed collections and the like.